Can the elements of this recursive sequence be calculated individually?
Is there a way to calculate each element of these sequences individually without having to calculate the previous element or sequence?
Sequence 1: [2]
Sequence 2: [4,  2,  6]
Sequence 3: [8,  4,  12, 2, 10,  6, 14]
Sequence 4: [16, 8,  24, 4, 20, 12, 28, 2, 18, 10, 26,  6, 22, 14, 30]
Sequence 5: [32, 16, 48, 8, 40, 24, 56, 4, 36, 20, 52, 12, 44, 28, 60, 2, 34, 18, 50, 10, 42, 26, 58, 6, 38, 22, 54, 14, 46, 30, 62]
etc.

I know how to generate them recursively, as the first half of the next sequence is just prev_sequence[i] * 2 and the second half is prev_sequence[i] * 2 + 2 (when you prefix 0 to the sequence).
There seems to be an internal pattern. Looking at e.g. the sequence 3, it starts with 8, the next two numbers are 8-4 = 4 and 8+4 = 12. The next four numbers are the last two interleaved, where the first half is number-2 and the second half is number+2. The sequence 4 starts the internal pattern with -8 and +8 then continues to half if for the next "levels".
I feel that this is more of a math question than a programming one, hence the question is here. I'm sorry for not phrasing my question in a more mathematical way.
Thanks to everyone in advance.

The first number is always zero, the second one is a power of $2$, the third one if one lesser power of $2$, then you get six-folds of powers of $2$, ... what did you find out?

@Dominique I'm sorry, I'm not sure if i understood your comment. You think the pattern has more complex relationship and it cannot be simply calculated for individual elements of the sequence?

He is looking at the data you have displayed and trying to find patterns. Which is what you can be doing too.

Ahh... I really misunderstood what he meant. I considered my findings irrelevant. At one point I came up with a formula that worked for at most 8 elements of the sequence, but then it fell apart. I was mostly looking at smaller pieces of the sequence from which I could later derive a formula for the whole sequence, but I had no luck.

All numbers in these sequences are even, so let's divide them by $2$. Here's how you get $\frac12\cdot$ sequence $k$: List the numbers $1,\ldots,2^k-1$ in binary as a $k$-digit number (with leading zeros) and read them backwards, again as binary numbers. For example, for $k=3$, the first seven natural numbers are $$001,010,011,100,101,110,111.$$ Read backwards, we get $$100_2=4_{10},010_2=2_{10},110_2=6_{10},001_2=1_{10},101_2=5_{10},011_2=3_{10},111_2=7_{10},$$ and if you double those you get exactly your sequence 3.

Let $a_{k,n}$ be the $n$-th entry of $\frac12$(sequence $k$). We prove the above claim by induction on $k$. In the following, everything is written in binary, $\overline x$ means the number you get from reversing the digits of $x$, and $x|y$ means concatination of the digits in $x$ and $y$, i.e. $10|11=1011$.
For $0<n<2^k$, we have $$a_{k+1,n}=2a_{k,n}=2\cdot\overline n=\overline n|0=\overline{0|n},$$ as expected. Similarly, $$a_{k+1,2^k+n}=2a_{k,n}+1=\overline n|1=\overline{1|n}.$$
This finishes the induction.

This conceptual description is far more useful than any formula, but if you insist on one, here it is: $$a_{k,n}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{k-1-i}\left(\left\lfloor\frac n{2^i}\right\rfloor\bmod 2\right)$$
This just relies on the part in parentheses computing the $i$-th bit, and multiplying with the correct power of $2$ to get that bit in the correct position. To get back to your sequences, you of course just have to multiply everything by $2$.

Another neat way to formulate this is via convolutions: We have $$a_{k,n}=((\text{the binary digits of $n$ as a string of length }k)\ast(1,2,4,8,\ldots))(k-1).$$

The description is definitely more useful than the formula itself. I am very grateful for the write-up and solving my problem.

Your sequences may be 'extracted' from the sequence OEIS A030109 :
The trick for the sequence $m$ is to reverse the bits of $2^m-1$ consecutive numbers (subract $1$ and divide by $2$) starting at $2^{m+1}+1$ :
pari/gp script :
g(n)= fromdigits(Vecrev(binary(n)),2)
s(m)=vector(2^m-1,n,(g(2^(m+1)+n)-1)/2)

> s(1)
%3 = [2]
> s(2)
%4 = [4, 2, 6]
> s(3)
%5 = [8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14]
> s(4)
%6 = [16, 8, 24, 4, 20, 12, 28, 2, 18, 10, 26, 6, 22, 14, 30]


The sequence I am looking for is indeed OEIS A030109. I completely forgot about the online encyclopedia of integer sequences. I should have checked there before I asked here. In any case, many thanks.
